# 'printing' HTML widgets in programmatically generated Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, htmlwidgets

I'm trying to programmatically generate some Rmarkdown and one of the sections contains an HTML widget. These are output fine if they are last in my function. However, if I wrap them in a `print` so I can put something else after them as you would do for a plot they do not produce any output.

Perhaps this some something to do with the way `knitr` handles printing i'm not sure. But does anyone know how I can get HTML widgets to behave like plots do in programmatically generated Rmarkdown?

Example .Rmd

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r}
ex_plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(iris, ggplot2::aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)) + 
    ggplot2::geom_point()

gen_rmarkdown_widget_last <- function() {
    cat("# Head 1\n\n")
    DT::datatable(iris)
}

gen_rmarkdown_plots <- function() {
    cat("# Head 1\n\n")
    print(ex_plot)
    cat("# Head 2\n\n")
}

gen_rmarkdown_widgets <- function() {
    cat("# Head 1\n\n")
    print(DT::datatable(iris))

    # tried loading from file
    # tmp <- tempfile()
    # htmlwidgets::saveWidget(DT::datatable(iris), tmp)
    # knitr::include_url(tmp)
    
    # tried a different widget
    # print(plotly::ggplotly(ex_plot))

    cat("# Head 2\n\n")
}

```

```{r, results='asis'}
# works fine
gen_rmarkdown_widget_last()
```

```{r, results='asis'}
# works fine
gen_rmarkdown_plots()
```

```{r, results='asis'}
# Can't have an HTML widget if it is followed by other things
gen_rmarkdown_widgets()
```
````

Comment: Try `print(htmltools::tagList(DT::datatable(iris)))`. Looks related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63532652/printing-any-number-of-dataframes-stored-in-list-as-paged-tables-in-rmarkdown/63533860#63533860

Comment: Interesting that adds an empty space where the widget would go between the headings but does not output the widget...

Comment: Hm Weird. I tested it on my machine. When I run your code just the headers get printed. Using `print(htmltools::tagList(DT::datatable(iris)))` outputs the DT after Head 1, followed by Head 2.

Comment: fascinating if I only run the `gen_rmarkdown_widgets` with your suggestion it does not work if I run working example `gen_rmarkdown_widget_last` first then `gen_rmarkdown_widgets` if works. Must be something to do with that initialisation thing mentioned in the post you linked to

Comment: Yep. Initalising is important to include the JS dependencies in the final HTML document.

Comment: Do you know of a way to 'manually' initialise the widget so that the appropriate JS is included in the document without making a call to DT or other widget that is not 'cached' in the `print`/`tagList` call and thus apparently not noticed by whatever `knitr` is doing to decide what JS to include?

Comment: I mean you can just stick a chunk like this in that seem very hackey:

 
 ```{r, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
 DT::datatable(data.frame())
 plotly::ggplotly(ggplot2::ggplot())
 ```

Comment: Haven't tried it myself. But I guess you could add some HTML to include the JS dependencies yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63534247/13513328).

Adding the dependencies manually is done with:

```
data.frame() %>%
  DT::datatable() %>%
  knitr::knit_print() %>%
  attr('knit_meta') %>%
  knitr::knit_meta_add() %>%
  invisible()
```

In the example you provided:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r}
library(dplyr)
#load dependencies
data.frame() %>%
  DT::datatable() %>%
  knitr::knit_print() %>%
  attr('knit_meta') %>%
  knitr::knit_meta_add() %>%
  invisible()

ex_plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(iris, ggplot2::aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)) + 
    ggplot2::geom_point()



gen_rmarkdown_widget_last <- function() {
    cat("# Head 1\n\n")
    DT::datatable(iris)
}

gen_rmarkdown_plots <- function() {
    cat("# Head 1\n\n")
    print(ex_plot)
    cat("# Head 2\n\n")
}

gen_rmarkdown_widgets <- function() {
    cat("# Head 1\n\n")
    cat(knitr::knit_print(DT::datatable(iris)))
    cat("\n  \n")
    cat("# Head 2\n\n")
}

```


```{r, results='asis'}
gen_rmarkdown_widgets()
```
````

[image]